# Do party members gain bonuses from using their "story" weapon?

Tags: mass-effect-3

In the DLC, the alien Javik introduces a particle rifle.

Is there any reason to arm him with that instead of using the best rifle in the game (found midway through the game)? It's a pretty lame rifle all things considered.

Does it even make any difference on squad effectiveness?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there are no extra bonuses for matching a particular character with a particular weapon.

One good benefit of equipping squad mates with this rifle is that it fires a continuous beam so its easy for you to see where the enemies are when your squad mates shoot them.

Comment: Very nice answer. The rifle does crap damage though. I end up playing every single game with a fully upgraded Black Widow going headshots only. I have a problem

Comment: @dsp_099 I highly recommend trying at least one playthrough as a charge/nova vanguard carrying nothing but a light smg or pistol.